# Qual a diferença entre: UrlEncode, EscapeUriString e EscapeDataString

Tags: c#

E qual dos três é equivalente ao `encodeURIComponent` do JavaScript?

String: *'apóstrofo' "aspas duplas" StackOverflow!*

```
string teste = "'apóstrofo' \"aspas duplas\" StackOverflow!";
HttpUtility.UrlEncode(teste); // %27ap%c3%b3strofo%27+%22aspas+duplas%22+StackOverflow!
Uri.EscapeUriString(teste); // 'ap%C3%B3strofo'%20%22aspas%20duplas%22%20StackOverflow!
Uri.EscapeDataString(teste); // %27ap%C3%B3strofo%27%20%22aspas%20duplas%22%20StackOverflow%21
```

Olhando os três resultados não consegui saber exatamente qual a maior diferença entre eles além de do `EscapeUriString` não escapar apóstrofo.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Todos estes métodos são relativos à `RFC 2396`, que define a sintaxe dos Identificadores Uniformes de Recursos (ou URI, do inglês Uniform Resource Identifiers) e, no caso de UrlEncode, também a `RFC 1738` (que define *Uniform Resource Locators*, ou URLs).

### UrlEncode

**Quando usar**: Quando precisar garantir que uma URL é válida, ou quando necessitar passar uma URL como parâmetro dentro de outra URL.
**Como funciona**: Converte todos os caracteres de controle ou reservados definidos na `RFC 1738` para seus equivalentes codificados, evitando assim que marcadores como espaço em branco (que poderia definir o fim do nome de um recurso) ou a contrabarra (que poderia definir um protocolo ou credenciais, dependendo da posição) sejam erroneamente interpretados.

### EscapeUriString

**Quando usar**: Quando precisar passar uma URI ao invés de uma URL.
**Como funciona**: Converte todos os caracteres (menos os descritos como não-reservados na `RFC 2396`) para representação hexadecimal. (este comportamento muda caso interpretação IRIs ou IDN estiver habilitada). Como o conjunto de caracteres reservados para URIs é diferente do conjunto para URLs, algumas URLs válidas podem ser mal-interpretadas (principalmente com o uso do sinal de mais [+].)

### EscapeDataString

**Quando usar**: Quando precisar passar dados em uma URI.
**Como funciona**: Realiza as mesmas transformações de `EscapeUriString`, porém inclui caracteres de controle considerados válidos para uma URI na conversão com o objetivo de permitir que os dados sejam corretamente intepretados como conteúdo e não como identificadores.

Você pode encontrar algumas tabelas de conversão entre formatos [aqui](https://web.archive.org/web/20160228174549/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/yangxind/archive/2006/11/09/don-t-use-net-system-uri-unescapedatastring-in-url-decoding.aspx).

Answer (score 6):

a UrlEncode Retorna uma string em que todos os caracteres não-alfanuméricos com exceção de -_. são substituídos com um sinal de porcento (%) seguido por dois dígitos hexadecimais e espaços codificados como um sinal de (+).

Ex.:

```
<?php
echo '<a href="mycgi?foo=', urlencode($userinput), '">';
?>
```

Você usa EscapeUriString se o que você está "escapando" é uma URI, e EscapeDataString em qualquer outro lugar.

Há diferenças em como os dois são codificados...

Mais informações aqui:

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160228174549/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/yangxind/archive/2006/11/09/don-t-use-net-system-uri-unescapedatastring-in-url-decoding.aspx)

Achei mais informações aqui:

http://blog.nerdbank.net/2009/05/uriescapedatapath-and.html