# Decodificar string codificada pelo javascript no c#

Tags: javascript, c#, winforms

Olá, é o seguinte.. No site que estou construindo, eu gravo uma informação no banco de dados, essa informação é um json, para conseguir enviar pro banco de dados esses dados, eu codifico eles pelo javascript assim:

```
encodeURI(dados);
```

Depois disso eu envio via jquery e gravo no banco de dados..

Até ai tudo beleza, só que preciso recuperar esses dados em um software do windows forms, em c#, estou a procura de uma maneira de decodificar essa informação, tentei essa:

```
using System;
using System.Net;

...
Conecto ao banco de dados, pego a informação do jeito que está la em um string, e peço pra mostrar numa show box
MessageBox.Show(WebUtility.HtmlDecode(pedidos));
```

Só que ele não está decodificando, o resultado ainda tá voltando igual tá no banco de dados, todo codificado como se fosse uma URI

```
%5B%0A%09%7B%0A%09%09%22id%22%3A%221%22%2C%0A%09%09%22produto%22%3A%22VENEZA%22%2C%0A%09%09%22preco%22%3A%2242.00%22%2C%0A%09%09%22quantidade%22%3A1%0A%09%7D%0A%5D
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tenta usar o `HttpUtility.UrlDecode` da biblioteca `System.Web`

```
String teste = "%5B%0A%09%7B%0A%09%09%22id%22%3A%221%22%2C%0A%09%09%22produto%22%3A%22VENEZA%22%2C%0A%09%09%22preco%22%3A%2242.00%22%2C%0A%09%09%22quantidade%22%3A1%0A%09%7D%0A%5D";

Console.WriteLine(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(teste));
```

Retorno:

```
[
    {
        "id":"1",
        "produto":"VENEZA",
        "preco":"42.00",
        "quantidade":1
    }
]
```

Leitura recomendada: [Qual a diferença entre: UrlEncode, EscapeUriString e EscapeDataString](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/26405/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-urlencode-escapeuristring-e-escapedatastring)

Comment: Então vi varios sites ensinando isso ai, mas eu importo a biblioteca System.Web, mas essa função HttpUtility não aparece como se ele não existisse

Comment: Da erro ao importar a biblioteca?

Comment: Ah, entendi agora, preciso adicionar ela como referencia, achei que bastava referenciar ela na classe..

Comment: Isso, caso não der certo, tenta: `Uri.UnescapeDataString`

Comment: As duas funcionaram, obrigada

Comment: Se a resposta lhe ajudou marque como aceita para ajudar outros que tiverem a mesma dúvida! :)